# Thread Mutual Exclusive Section

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Hello I just had phone interview I was not able to answer this question and would like to know the answer, I believe, its advisable to reach out for answers that you don't know. Please encourage me to understand the concept.

His question was:

"The synchronized block only allows one thread a time into the mutual exclusive section. 
When a thread exits the synchronized block, the synchronized block does not specify 
which of the waiting threads will be allowed next into the mutual exclusive section?
 Using synchronized and methods available in Object, can you implement first-come, 
first-serve mutual exclusive section?  One that guarantees that threads are let into 
the mutual exclusive section in the order of arrival? "

```
 public class Test {
   public static final Object obj = new Object();

   public void doSomething() {
     synchronized (obj) {
          // mutual exclusive section
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Interesting question (+1). My inclination is to say "no, you can't do this solely with the methods in `Object` and the `synchronized` keyword." I am curious to know, though: are you **only** allowed to use `synchronized` and methods in `Object`?

Comment: @matt you are forgetting `wait()` and `notify()` alongside a FIFO queue

Comment: Can some one make me understand what question is all about ? :)

Comment: @ratchet I did consider just suggesting a re-implementation of, say, `LinkedBlockingQueue` but I'm not sure if that would still fall under the interviewer's definition of _"Using synchronized and methods available in Object."_ (btw queues are by definition FIFO)

Comment: @matt if arrays are considered to be objects (and array accesses a method of an array) it's easy enough to implement one on top of it ;)

Comment: @ratchet freak - it's *not* easy to implement a thread-safe queue on top of array that doesn't require any locking. And with locking, you are back to the original problem, only for shorter windows of time.

Comment: @erickson if that window of time is short enough you can explain anything else away with jitter right before the call to get the lock; but unless you have an atomic CompareAndSet to remove the locking to ensure the fairness of the lock you won't be able to get around it only using volatile reads and writes

Comment: interesting question but really unfair for an interview situation I feel!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple example:

```
public class FairLock {
    private int _nextNumber;
    private int _curNumber;

    public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        int myNumber = _nextNumber++;
        while(myNumber != _curNumber) {
            wait();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void unlock() {
        _curNumber++;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

you would use it like:

```
public class Example {
  private final FairLock _lock = new FairLock();

  public void doSomething() {
    _lock.lock();
    try {
      // do something mutually exclusive here ...
    } finally {
      _lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

(note, this does *not* handle the situation where a caller to lock() receives an interrupted exception!)

Comment: This is another solution that minimizes the time window where the threads can get out of order, but it doesn't eliminate it. This would be a great interview answer though, if you could explain that this is about as good as you can get without a non-blocking queue.

Comment: @erickson - in a multithreaded system you _cannot_ "eliminate" the time window.  even with a non-blocking queue, a "later" caller could get in front of an "earlier" caller.  the only thing you can do is narrow down the window as far as possible.  this solution is pretty much as narrow as you can get in the jvm.  in fact, a ConcurrentLinkedQueue (as you mentioned above) could end up being _worse_ in a highly contended system as it can live-lock.

Comment: I didn't realize `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is susceptible to live-locking, but that makes sense. So I guess the ultimate answer is, "no, you can't guarantee order-of-arrival execution." I was reluctant to say that because I held out hope for a concurrent queue.

Answer (score 3):

what they were asking is a fair mutex

create a FIFO queue of lock objects that are pushed on it by threads waiting for the lock and then wait on it (all this except the waiting in a synchronized block on a separate lock)

then when the lock is released an object is popped of the queue and the thread waiting on it woken (also synchronized on the same lock for adding the objects)

Comment: I don't think you can use FIFO queue... Can you do that with using Object's methods and synchronised?

Comment: @jarek arrays are considered objects in java it's a neat little loophole here ;)

Comment: true :)... nice loophole, but still would like to see an implementation of it. I smell it's gonna be difficult to write a race-resilient solution here this way.

Comment: You'd have to re-implement a non-blocking queue like `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` to preserve order-of-arrival, and even then you could have arguments about what "order of arrival" even means given the Java memory and concurrency models. Implementing your own simple queue by synchronizing access to an array is just minimizing the problem, not eliminating it.

Comment: @ratchet freak: I would like to see an implementation of your idea: it would be very helpful and instructive!

Comment: > "also synchronized on the same lock for adding the objects" - in this case you return to the root problem - unfairness of java sync

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ReentrantLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) with fairness parameter set to true. Then the next thread served will be the thread waiting for the longest time i.e. the one that arrived first.

Comment: Definitely would work, but it's not really clear if using `java.util.concurrent` classes is allowed within the scope of the interview question.

Comment: No, it's not allowed after I read the question more carefully :(.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. The idea to give a ticket number for each thread. Threads are entered based on the order of their ticket numbers.  I am not familiar with Java, so please read my comments:

```
 public class Test {
    public static final Object obj = new Object();
    unsigned int count = 0;  // unsigned global int
    unsigned int next  = 0;  // unsigned global int

    public void doSomething() {
       unsigned int my_number;  // my ticket number

       // the critical section is small. Just pick your ticket number. Guarantee FIFO
       synchronized (obj) { my_number = count ++; } 

       // busy waiting
       while (next != my_number);

       // mutual exclusion

       next++;  // only one thread will modify this global variable
    }
 }
```

The disadvantage of this answer is the busy waiting which will consume CPU time.

Comment: Aside from the invalid `unsigned` keyword, this won't work. Many threads are reading and writing the `next` member without a memory barrier. This is not guaranteed to give the results you expect. A JVM is free to optimize this code so that, for example, a waiting thread never sees an increment to `next` made by another thread.

Comment: @erickson. Thanks for your comments. As i said i am not familiar with Java. My understanding how to achieve FIFO using a single mutex. My answer is suggesting to declare two shared variables `count and next` and one local variable as illustratred above in my code. It's quite surprizing that a thread can modify a member variable accidently. I really don't know how the JVM shares variable. It is interesting to know. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: At least my answer inspired some other people

Answer (score 0):

Using only Object's method and synchronized, in my point of view is a little difficult. Maybe, by setting each thread a priority, you can garantee an ordered access to the critical section.